# Calling Hooks From An OnClick Event

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a file **Global.js** that has two methods that i plan to use accross my React app.

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useEffect } from 'react';

function CheckLoginExpiry() {
    console.log('Begin CheckLoginExpiry');

    const navigate = useNavigate();
    useEffect(() => {
        if (localStorage.getItem('loginExpiry') === null) {
            navigate('/Login');
        }
        if (Date(Date.now) > Date(localStorage.getItem('loginExpiry'))) {
            navigate('/Login');
        }
    });
    console.log('End CheckLoginExpiry');
}

function HandleLogout() {
    console.log('Begin HandleLogout');
    localStorage.clear();
    CheckLoginExpiry();
    console.log('End HandleLogout');
}

export { HandleLogout, CheckLoginExpiry };
```

The issue occurs when I call the `HandleLogout()` function in an onClick event. For example, in a button in **Home.js**:

```
<input className="logout_button" type="button" onClick={HandleLogout} value="Logout" />
```

When i click on the button, I get the error: *Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.*
And when I checked the suggested [page](https://react.dev/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning) for handling the common causes of the error, I saw that there is a section about calling react hooks from event handlers (which I think is referring to my case) but I couldn't deduce what to do from that sample. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Hi, hooks can only be called inside a component or custom hook.
If what you are trying to achieve is a logout button and a check on wether the "session" is expired or not before a user can access a page, i'd suggest you only clear the localStorage on click and then check the localStorage before acessing any page and redirect there if needed

Answer (score 0):

you're getting that error because when you call `HandleLogout` inside your onClick event, also calls `CheckLoginExpiry`, and that's like executing the `useNavigate()` and `useEffect()` hook on your onClick event, and hooks can only be called in function component body.

Something I'd do is turn that `CheckLoginExpiry` function into a custom hook.

```
export const useCheckLoginExpiry = () => {
  
const navigate = useNavigate();

  const checkLoginExpiry = () => {
    if (localStorage.getItem('loginExpiry') === null) {
      navigate('/Login');
    }
    if (Date(Date.now) > Date(localStorage.getItem('loginExpiry'))) {
        navigate('/Login');
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    checkLoginExpiry()
  });

  const handleLogout = () => {
    console.log('Begin HandleLogout');
    localStorage.clear();
    checkLoginExpiry();
    console.log('End HandleLogout');
  }

  return { handleLogout }
}

const Home = () => {
  const { handleLogout } = useCheckLoginExpiry()

  return <input className="logout_button" type="button" onClick={handleLogout} value="Logout" />
}
```